# Sprouts (Graph Theory) with vertices of higher maximum degree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

There has been substantial Graph Theory research on who will win a game of [sprouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouts_(game)) given the number of vertices, but I was wondering if there is any research on who will win if we fix the number of vertices, but allow the maximum degree of each vertex to be a number other than 3. This is trivial for a max degree of 1 or 2, but (by playing a few games) gets much more complicated for a max degree of 4, 5, etc. I was curious if there has been any research on this and/or if one could generalize the winning strategy on a fixed number of vertices with a max degree of three to a winning strategy on the fixed number of vertices with a max degree of n.

Answer (score 1):

Lets call stubs the potential half-links that can be drawn. Initially, the number of stubs in sprouts is $3n$ where $n$ is the number of starting spots.
In combinatorial game theory, in order to prove the existence of a winning strategy, we generally ensure that the game will eventually end.
In the game of sprouts, this condition is verified because the sum of stubs decreases by exactly one at each move (two are removed by creating a link, one is added by splitting an edge). If you increase the maximal degree of the graph, the number of stubs increase at each step, and there is no guaranty that the game will eventually end. In fact, it's even worse, as each player is guaranteed to always have a move at each turn, as you can always add a self-loop on the newly created spot.